# Package dependendency error, even though the package is the correct version

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Okay, I'm trying to install bsdtar, but it won't let me, it marks a package dependency error, even though the the package it marks the error for is on the same version as required.

Here's the result of running $ sudo apt-get install bsdtar

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bsdtar : Depends: libarchive13 (= 3.1.2-9) but 3.1.2-9ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have also tried to install using $ sudo aptitude install bsdtar with the following results:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
aptitude is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
pablo@Carcacha:~$ sudo aptitude install bsdtar
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bsdtar{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
Need to get 47.8 kB of archives. After unpacking 129 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bsdtar : Depends: libarchive13 (= 3.1.2-9) but 3.1.2-9ubuntu0.1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     bsdtar [Not Installed]                             



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used
```

Thanks in advance, all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's where it gets tricky and EXTREMELY confusing.
Yes you do have libarchive installed BUT you have the wrong version of the proper version. For reasons thst I never understood Ubuntu puts the word ubuntu into most lib files.

What you need to do is, do an online search and libarchive13 version 3.1.2.9 without the Ubuntu suffex, download and install IT. The fact that you now have 2 versions of the same thing usually doesn't matter as to the OS they're different.

I really wish the different distributors quit this kind of crap, it just makes it harder for the user.